# Magento Page Speed Issue

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, performance

Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content

Your page has 27 blocking script resources and 4 blocking CSS resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page.

```
 Remove render-blocking JavaScript:
    https://myweb/…js/smartwave/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js
    https://myweb/…twave/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js
    https://myweb/…js/smartwave/jquery/jquery-noconflict.js
    https://myweb/js/smartwave/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js
    https://myweb/…y/plugins/fancybox/js/jquery.fancybox.js
    https://myweb/js/smartwave/ajaxcart/ajaxaddto.js
    https://myweb/js/varien/product.js
    https://myweb/js/varien/configurable.js
    https://myweb/js/calendar/calendar.js
    https://myweb/js/calendar/calendar-setup.js
    https://myweb/…ry/plugins/etalage/jquery.etalage.min.js
    https://myweb/…query/plugins/etalage/jquery.zoom.min.js
    https://myweb/…cybox/js/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js
    https://myweb/…ry/plugins/selectbox/jquery.selectbox.js
    https://myweb/…y/plugins/parallax/jquery.stellar.min.js
    https://myweb/…uery/plugins/parallax/jquery.parallax.js
    https://myweb/js/smartwave/jquery/jquery.cookie.js
    https://myweb/…plugins/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js
    https://myweb/…/smartwave/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js
    https://myweb/…d/smartwave/porto/js/lib/imagesloaded.js
    https://myweb/…ave/porto/js/configurableswatches/app.js
    https://myweb/…/smartwave/porto/megamenu/js/megamenu.js
    https://myweb/skin/frontend/base/default/js/bundle.js
    https://myweb/…twave/porto/quickview/js/sw_quickview.js
    https://myweb/…default/socialfeeds/js/twitterfetcher.js
    https://myweb/…n/frontend/smartwave/porto/js/wow.min.js
    https://myweb/…kin/frontend/smartwave/porto/js/porto.js
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: you need to combine them into one file and load after head and body start, probably in footer

Answer (score 1):

go to setting and enable css and js merge from your admin panel

Goto `System->configuration->Advanced->Developer->JavaScript Settings` and set `Merge JavaScript Files` to `yes`

Do same for css

Goto `System->configuration->Advanced->Developer->CSS Settings` and set `Merge CSS Files` to `yes`

Comment: After enabling js and CSS, front and home page completely collapsed.

Comment: check js error in console and copy paste and validate css on w3c validator

Comment: I've learned `Merge JS` ony works for prototype scripts. As soon you (we) added some jQuery stuff, merging didn't work correctly.

Comment: No @sv3n if you have js proper way then your js Works fine, but if you written Js improper way then only merging will cause problem to you, In my all site I am using merging I never Faced problem Or else I find out the js which causing problem and repair that js code

Comment: Thanks @Martuza. Then it came from 3rd-party-scripts i haven't checked.